# ThresholdImageOps.threshold() doesn't work(Android)

Tags: android, threshold, boofcv

After the import of `boofcv-android` and `boofcv-core` libraries I'm trying to use the `ThresholdImageOps.threshold(...)` function but it doesn't seem to work.
Also, tried `GThresholdImageOps.threshold(...)`, without any success.
[image]

Comment: This this issue: https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofCV/issues/135

Comment: Just to double check, you have the import statement for ThresholdImageOps, correct?

Comment: @lessthanoptimal
Yes.
The bug was fixed, see the new comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, strangely, was to catch the return value:
[image]